# ¿Cómo puedo filtrar registros con rango de fechas especificando la hora de inicio y final del registro?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy filtrando registros en **SQL** por rango de fechas y la misma consulta, estoy especificando la hora inicio y final para que me cargue la información, pero cuando agrego una fecha diferente.

Por ejemplo:

2023-07-19 a 2023-07-20 con horario de 22:00 a 06:00.

No me cargan todos los registros, me cargan solo 4 registros.

Esta es mi consulta:

```
 select * from TarimasC t where t.FInicio between '2023-07-19' and '2023-07-20' and t.HInicio >= '22:00:00' and t.HFin <= '06:00:00'
```

Los campos **HInicio** y **HFin** son campos separados. Espero su ayuda. Saludos...

Gestor de base de datos : Sql-Server 2008

Comment: Puedes colocar el esquema de la tabla? Además que motor de base de datos estas usando?

Comment: Posiblemente no te están saliendo los registros de 2023-07-20 puesto que que al no colocar hora se asume las 00:00 horas por lo que basta un fracción de segundo después de esa fecha para ya no estar considerada en el intervalo

Comment: Estoy usando Sql server 2008, solo tengo detalle en el rango de horas . Intenté modificar la consulta de varias formas pero me siguen cargan los mismos 4 registros cuando supuestamente me deben de cargar varios porque existen registros en ese rango de fechas. El detalle es cuando agrego el rango de hora inicio y final.

Comment: Como te mencioné, coloca el esquema (script de creación) de tu tabla para saber que está pasando exactamente

Comment: Adjunté la estructura de la tabla con los tipos de datos. Espero sea suficiente . saludos

Comment: No lo coloques como imagen sino coloca el código, y puedes omitir los campos irrelevantes y dejar solo aquellos referenciados por tu query